# pd.merge_asof() based on Time-Difference not merging all values - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with news and the other with stock price. Both the dataframes have a "Date" column. I want to merge them on a gap of 5 days.

Lets say my news dataframe is df1 and the other price dataframe as df2.

My df1 looks like this:

```
News_Dates             News
2018-09-29     Huge blow to ABC Corp. as they lost the 2012 tax case
2018-09-30     ABC Corp. suffers a loss
2018-10-01     ABC Corp to Sell stakes
2018-12-20     We are going to comeback strong said ABC CEO
2018-12-22     Shares are down massively for ABC Corp.
```

My df2 looks like this:

```
  Dates             Price
2018-10-04           120
2018-12-24           131
```

First method of merging I do is:

```
pd.merge_asof(df1_zscore.sort_values(by=['Dates']), df_n.sort_values(by=['News_Dates']), left_on=['Dates'], right_on=['News_Dates'] \
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5d'), direction='backward')
```

The resulting df is:

```
  Dates       News_Dates   News                                     Price
2018-10-04    2018-10-01  ABC Corp to Sell stakes                    120
2018-12-24    2018-12-22  Shares are down massively for ABC Corp.    131
```

The second way of merging I do is:

```
pd.merge_asof(df_n.sort_values(by=['Dates']), df1_zscore.sort_values(by=['Dates']), left_on=['News_Dates'], right_no=['Dates'] \
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5d'), direction='forward').dropna()
```

And the resulting df as:

```
News_Dates            News                                                Dates      Price
2018-09-29     Huge blow to ABC Corp. as they lost the 2012 tax case    2018-10-04    120
2018-09-30     ABC Corp. suffers a loss                                 2018-10-04    120 
2018-10-01     ABC Corp to Sell stakes                                  2018-10-04    120
2018-12-22     Shares are down massively for ABC Corp.                  2018-12-24    131
```

Both the merging results in separate dfs, however there are values in both the cases which are missing, like for second case for 4th October price, news from 29th, 30th Sept should have been merged. And in case 2 for 24th December price 20th December should also have been merged.

So I'm not quite able to figure out where am I going wrong.

P.S. My objective is to merge the price df with the news df that have come in the last 5 days from the price date.

Comment: Why don't you swap left and right dataframes in merge_asof?  You can use direction='nearest' as well to go in both forward and backward direction on merge.

Comment: I don't need the other part, I need for only last 5 days, next  5 days is not required at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using numpy

```
df_n = pd.DataFrame([('2018-09-29', 'Huge blow to ABC Corp. as they lost the 2012 tax case'), ('2018-09-30', 'ABC Corp. suffers a loss'), ('2018-10-01', 'ABC Corp to Sell stakes'), ('2018-12-20', 'We are going to comeback strong said ABC CEO'), ('2018-12-22', 'Shares are down massively for ABC Corp.')], columns=('News_Dates', 'News'))
df1_zscore = pd.DataFrame([('2018-10-04', '120'), ('2018-12-24', '131')], columns=('Dates', 'Price'))

df_n["News_Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df_n["News_Dates"])
df1_zscore["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df1_zscore["Dates"])
```

```py
n_dates = df_n["News_Dates"].values
p_dates = df1_zscore[["Dates"]].values

## substract each pair of n_dates and p_dates and create a matrix
mat_date_compare = (p_dates - n_dates).astype('timedelta64[D]')

## get matrix of boolean for which difference is between 0 and 5 day
## to be used as index for original array
comparision =  (mat_date_compare <= pd.Timedelta("5d")) & (mat_date_compare >= pd.Timedelta("0d"))

## get cell numbers which is in range 0 to matrix size which meets the condition
ind = np.arange(len(n_dates)*len(p_dates))[comparision.ravel()]


## calculate row and column index from cell number to index the df
pd.concat([df1_zscore.iloc[ind//len(n_dates)].reset_index(drop=True), 
           df_n.iloc[ind%len(n_dates)].reset_index(drop=True)], sort=False, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
Dates   Price   News_Dates  News
0   2018-10-04  120 2018-09-29  Huge blow to ABC Corp. as they lost the 2012 t...
1   2018-10-04  120 2018-09-30  ABC Corp. suffers a loss
2   2018-10-04  120 2018-10-01  ABC Corp to Sell stakes
3   2018-12-24  131 2018-12-20  We are going to comeback strong said ABC CEO
4   2018-12-24  131 2018-12-22  Shares are down massively for ABC Corp.
```

Comment: why -1 to the answer? if this solution not working please comment why and give me change to improve it

Comment: hey, the solution is not working for me. its merging even 2019 data, and moreover I didn't downvote. Do I have to set the index to dates for both the df?
If you print `df1_zscore[within_days_indx]` you'll get to see that something is not correct

Comment: no dates not to be index of the dataframe, I have added dataframe initialization code also, it is working for me you can try the whole code

Comment: hey worked for me now, my df was not sorted on Dates

Comment: @DebadriDutta there was small mistake on how the index was used, I correct it now plz update you code

Answer (score 2):

You can swap the left and right dataframe:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(
        df1,
        df2,
        left_on='News_Dates',
        right_on='Dates',
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta('5D'),
        direction='nearest'
    )

df = df[['Dates', 'News_Dates', 'News', 'Price']]
print(df)

        Dates News_Dates                                               News Price
0 2018-10-04 2018-09-29  Huge blow to ABC Corp. as they lost the 2012 t... 120
1 2018-10-04 2018-09-30                           ABC Corp. suffers a loss 120
2 2018-10-04 2018-10-01                            ABC Corp to Sell stakes 120
3 2018-12-24 2018-12-20       We are going to comeback strong said ABC CEO 131
4 2018-12-24 2018-12-22            Shares are down massively for ABC Corp. 131
```

Comment: can u please explain why `nearest` works and `backward`/`forward` doesn't? And also then if it had been next 5 days than would it have been `'-5D'` instead of `'5D'`

Comment: Forward would also work.  The left dataframe (df1) is merging on df2 which has dates in the futures so forward will work.  I tend to default to nearest as my go to.  You can test out your theory from there.

Comment: If there are duplicates happening they are not getting merged, for ex. if I'm having a price on 3rd Oct, 4th Oct and news are there on 2nd and 3rd Oct, the 2nd Oct news are not getting merged with 4th Oct one